# Excel VBA - Scoping Const Variable to be Accessed only by Current Project

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic, global

I have an Excel Add-in for storage of UDF's as well as a personal workbook for storage of subroutines.

Inside of the Add-in, I have a module for constants, where I have an entry for ideal gas constant:

```
Global Const r = 8.314 'Same result using Global or Public
```

This "global" constant can be accessed from all modules within the Excel Add-in and the personal workbook.

My issue is that I would like to be able to limit the scope of this variable to only the modules of the add-in and no other open projects.  Otherwise, I need to keep track in all open projects as to what variables I'm declaring as Global.  Eventually, I'll end up like NASA, getting my units confused...

Thanks all for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Global` is an obsolete keyword; the only difference between `Global` and `Public` is that you can't use `Global` in a class module. Prefer `Public` for consistency.

Use the little-known [`Friend`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/friend-keyword) access modifier to make a member accessible everywhere inside the project it's declared in, but only within that project.

The caveat is that it's only usable in a class module, and only for procedures - you can't make a `Friend Const`.

A work-around could be to leverage the hidden `VB_PredeclaredId` class attribute and set it to `True` - create a new text file in Notepad, with this content:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "StaticClass1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit
```

Save the file with a `.cls` extension, then import it into your project.

Then you can rename it to something more meaningful, and expose a `Friend Property Get` member:

```
Friend Property Get R() As Single
    R = 8.314
End Property
```

And now you can use that value, but only within the project that contains this class. Because of  the `PredeclaredId` attribute, you don't need to create a `New` instance:

```
Debug.Print StaticClass1.R ' 8.314
```

Sadly (?) the `VB_GlobalNamespace` attribute has no effect in VBA user classes, so the qualifying object (the predeclared class instance has the same name as the class module itself - that's exactly how `UserForm1.Show` can work) is required.

> **Caution:** it can be tempting to store instance state (e.g. private module-level variables) on a default instance (especially in forms), but it should be avoided whenever possible. If you need to store state, consider working with a `New` instance of the class instead. Stateful default instances are more prone to bugs, notably because the object's lifetime is managed by the VBA run-time, not by user code. If the default instance is recycled/recreated, any state previously held is reset to whatever the design-time defaults are.

Note that class modules are *private* by default, which already makes them invisible to other referencing projects. You can change the *Instancing* property of the class to make it `PublicNotCreatable`, which will change the value of it `VB_Exposed` attribute to `True`:

```
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
```

Public classes can be accessed from outside the project, but can't be created directly with the `New` keyword (changing the value of the `VB_Creatable` attribute has no effect in VBA). With a public/exposed class, referencing projects will be able to invoke the `Public` members, but not the `Friend` ones:

```
Public Property Get UseMeAnywhere() As Long
    UseMeAnywhere = 42
End Property

Friend Property Get YouOnlySeeMeInThisProject() As Long
    YouOnlySeeMeInThisProject = 42
End Property
```

Comment: Thank you, this works so well!  I've set the scope of the new Class to "PublicNotCreatable", which I'm surmising negated the creation of the class from notepad.  If I do want to use this constant outside of the current project, I still need to point the calling project to the appropriate project identifier and class name, e.g. "mjFunctions.Constants.R".  I'm assuming there's no other way to access this class property from outside of the "mjFunctions" add-in.

Comment: In addition, even accessing this property from within "mjFunctions" requires me to specify the "Constants" class, which should greatly prevent against confusion.

Comment: @MichaelJames Yes! Explicit qualifiers are always a very good thing! IMO the `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute is the single most useful hidden VBA gem. With it you can expose a public parameterized *factory method* that creates & returns an initialized new instance of the class, so you can then do e.g. `Set coord = GridCoord.Create(4, 2)`. Note that [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) surfaces these attributes with special annotation comments, and automatically synchronizes hidden attributes with the annotations, so `'@PredeclaredId` at the top, synchronize, and done!

Comment: Is there any way to access the Class Attributes without creating the class in notepad and importing?

Comment: @MichaelJames yes, with the Rubberduck add-in (an open-source project I contribute to) you can just add `'@PredeclaredId` at the top, and/or `'@ModuleDescription("This module contains important stuff")`, and a [bunch of others](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/VB_Attribute-Annotations). Desynchronized attributes/annotations show up under "Rubberduck Opportunities" in the *inspection results* toolwindow, and then a quick-fix can automatically synchronize them.

Answer (score 1):

A fix would be adding an Option Private statement to the declaration section of the module. 
This will limit the scope to only the project that the module sits within, not any open project. Link included below from Microsoft Docs for how to do this specifically.

For more information on scope and visibility see the link below from the Microsoft Docs:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-private-statement

*edit 04/22/2019: Took out the piece around Public to Global variable identifier as this didn't fix the problem.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Unfortunately, I've tested both Global and Public.  Both allow access to the variable from all open projects.  In case this is version-related, this issue is being seen in VBA for Excel 2016.

Comment: `Option Private Module` is the simplest solution - I always forget about that option. Note that the distinction between `Global` and `Public` in this answer is rather misleading though. Consider [edit]ing it out.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion - I took out the piece around the {global} / {public} identifiers.